# Blurriness because of custom CSS (Semantic UI React)

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I've made a `LoginLayout` container for my Login page:

```
class LoginLayout extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="auth-main">
        <div class="auth-content">
          <div className="auth-card">
            <img src={logo} alt="Logo" className="auth-logo" />
            <Header as="h2" color="black" textAlign="center">
              {this.props.header}
            </Header>
            <Form.Group size="large" className="auth-form" autocomplete="off">
              {this.props.children}
            </Form.Group>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the `.css` file for it:

```
.auth-main {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.auth-content {
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.auth-card {
    border-radius: 1%;
    min-width: 300px;
}

.auth-logo {
    width : 75%;
    margin: 5%
}

.auth-form {
    margin: 10%;
}
```

And this is the way I've nested the Login forms inside this `LoginLayout`:

```
return (
    <div>
      <LoginLayout header="Sign up to get started">
        <Form onSubmit={postLogin}>
          <Form.Input
          ...
      </LoginLayout>
```

The result positioned the elements well but the whole sharpness of the content seems to be reduced.

I've opened another Chrome window to compare it with the Register page which is the same but without any Layout component around it.

Stackoverflow has reduced image quality as well, but the difference is still noticable:

[image]

What is the reason behind this change in sharpness? Is it the resizing or some hidden CSS property? Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've tried to rule out every css property one by one. It seems the blurriness was caused by the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` property. Without it the content is just the same again as before, only not alligned to the center so an alternative way is needed for that.

I've no answers at the moment why translating causes reduction in sharpness.